# How to use date_trunc with timezone in Ecto fragment statement

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I'm trying to query for orders of a shop and `date_trunc` its `inserted_at` using the shop's timezone.

The following worked.

```
shop |> Ecto.assoc(:orders) |> select([o], fragment("date_trunc('day', ? at time zone 'America/Los_Angeles')", o.inserted_at)) |> Repo.all
```

But when I try to dynamically pass in the timezone, I get "could not determine data type of parameter $1" error even though I explicitly used `type` to cast the timezone as a string

```
shop |> Ecto.assoc(:orders) |> select([o], fragment("date_trunc('day', ? at time zone '?')", o.inserted_at, type(^timezone, :string))) |> Repo.all


** (Postgrex.Error) ERROR 42P18 (indeterminate_datatype): could not determine data type of parameter $1
[debug] QUERY ERROR source="orders" db=1.0ms
SELECT date_trunc('day', o0."inserted_at" at time zone '$1::varchar') FROM "orders" AS o0 WHERE (o0."shop_id" = $2) ["America/Los_Angeles", "QXJnQWw2NWxhS289"]
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:436: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.execute_and_cache/7
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:130: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.execute/5
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:35: Ecto.Repo.Queryable.all/4
```

Using elixir 1.4.1 and ecto 2.1.4 here.

How to get the query right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try removing the single quote around `?` for the timezone: `fragment("date_trunc('day', ? at time zone ?)", ...)`.

Comment: @Dogbert it worked! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need quotes in the SQL around `?` when using `fragment` (and neither do you need the explicit type cast after you've fixed the quote error):

```
shop |> Ecto.assoc(:orders) |> select([o], fragment("date_trunc('day', ? at time zone ?)", o.inserted_at, ^timezone)) |> Repo.all
```